# Difference in event bubbling of different `on` method signatures

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is difference between

```
$('root selector').on('click',function(){})
```

and

```
$('root').on('click', 'selector', function(){})
```

I want to know specifically about event bubbling.

Comment: I've read the doc completely but was not able understand the difference

Comment: Also [What is the difference between jquery on with / without selector parameter and jquery delegate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662041/what-is-the-difference-between-jquery-on-with-without-selector-parameter-and-j)